# Is it possible to run logrotate manually

Tags: linux

I created new files in

```
/etc/logrotate.d/
```

how run an iteration of logrotate manually to check these?

Comment: Top google result of "run logrotate" -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117771/is-it-possible-to-run-one-logrotate-check-manually

Comment: This question is being voted for closure because the author has not performed a minimum amount of research into the question that is otherwise immediately solved by a basic search. In other words, ServerFault is not Google as a Service.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try with:

```
logrotate --force $CONFIG_FILE
```

or you can run it in verbose and force mode:

```
logrotate -vf /etc/logrotate.conf
```

Answer (score 4):

You can run logrotate in debug mode which will tell you what it would do without actually making changes.

> -d, --debug
>
> Turns on debug mode and implies -v. In debug mode, no changes will be made to the logs or to the logrotate state file.